# Montreal Pizza sauce

Tags: sauce, pizza, restaurant-mimicry

I may be partial having lived there most of my life, but now that I live far away, I miss Montreal Pizza.  I can't seem to find a restaurant near me that has a similar flavor or any combination of ingredients that matches the flavor.

Do you have a recipe for the pizza sauce they use in Montreal pizzerias?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: @Paul, welcome to Seasoned Advice. Unfortunately, recipe requests are off topic. Maybe if you changed what you are asking to something along the lines of "What makes Montreal pizza sauce taste unique compared to other pizza sauces?", it would work but if left as is it will most likely be closed.

Comment: @duchessofstokesay - we actually allow really specific "copy this restaurant's recipe" style requests because those have a defined answer.  So if Montreal pizza sauce is really done only one way and Paul provides tons of specifics we might be able to help.  [Here's a recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipes/recipe.html?dishid=11623) from Toronto.  It has anchovies and capers, two things I don't use in Chicago or NY-style pizza sauce.

Comment: I have never noticed any particular similarity amongst pizza establishments in Montreal ... which places did you frequent?  Are you looking for the taste of the 99 cent cheese pizza, which is the only kind I guess might similar between various places?

Comment: @justkt: True, but are a large percentage of places in one city going to use the same exact recipe? I understand there might be similarities between the recipes but I don't think that all pizzerias are going to use the same sauce. That is all. =)

Comment: @duchessofstokesay - [this article](http://www.montrealgazette.com/opinion/letters/Montreal+school+pizza/4423732/story.html) defines Montreal Pizza, which appears to be a pizza with a standard definition like NY or Chicago.  That means characteristics of the sauce can be providied.

Comment: @justkt: I'm not so sure that the sauce itself is prescribed. Seems to just be what every non-Montreal pizzeria calls a "deluxe".

Comment: Perhaps it would help if Paul clarified where else he has eaten pizza. If montreal is the only place he has eaten pizza aside from where he lives now, it might be that the montreal pizza he is used to is generic, and the unique pizza that served where he currently resides.

Comment: Wholesaler supplies may be a factor too. I have noticed in various parts of the world significant numbers of food producers all buying the core flavour ingredients from one wholesaler in the region, giving everyone the same flavour characteristic. e.g. Spice mix for Easter hot cross buns, it's a once a year thing, not a shop speciality. So bakers just buy a sack of pre-mixed spice from the wholesaler in the region. The nett effect is that for 500 Km in any direction all hot cross buns taste the same! Even the local candy maker used it for Easter rolled candy, with exactly the same taste

Comment: Montreal Pizza is rather unique, the crust is very different from NY or Chicago style and the sauce is as well.. A bit tangier? They also have cold pizza slabs that are served with just the sauce which is amazing and my family has not been able to find anywhere else.

Comment: Could the secret ingredient be sundried tomatoes? This recipe for tomato sauce is from Montreal and contains besides sundried tomatoes a carrot and some parsley http://books.google.com/books?id=tg6oxznTpY0C&pg=PT327&dq=montreal+pizza+sauce+recipe&hl=en&ei=sYaxToq3F8fk4QSwq7DXAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Smoked paprika? A local pizzeria makes a pie similar to one I had in Montreal years ago, and the ingredient that stands out for me is the Paprika. I'm not sure, though, if this is the flavour you refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this article](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Great-Pizza) from a Montreal Pizzeria owner, hope its what you were looking for! :-)

The ingredients for Pizzazz Pizza (Montreal, 1989) sauce are:

> - 3 tbsp Pure Olive Oil 45 ml
> - 3 medium garlic cloves
> - 1/2 medium onion diced
> - 1 tsp salt
> - 1 tsp sugar
> - 1 tsp oregano
> - 1 tsp chili or one fresh halapino [sic] pepper
> - 5 basil leaves
> - 3 28oz cans san marzano tomatoes (whole tomatoes)

Also included in the link is crust, construction and an alternative sauce. Be aware that this recipe is par for 4 16" pizzas, so either adjust as necessary or invite over some friends to share!

Comment: It may be the chili/jalapeno is the distinguishing ingredient.

Comment: and the basil, sorry SAJ you posted the alternative sauce recipe... thanks for the help editing tho!

Comment: This sounds like a great, no tricks tomato sauce, no secret stuff in there :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I'll put a little input for those in the future who wish for Montreal Pizza. So basically I can't give a recipe but I do know what the person is talking about. The one thing I know for sure that Montreal has in the sauce is Fennel seeds and in the crust they may have put a little milk in the mix. As for the pizza with just the tomato sauce on top, it's called a Rosso Romano, it's a rectangle pizza with just tomato sauce. You can find these recipes online somewhere, so happy hunting for that pizza.